# Summation inside the integration in R

Tags: r

I would like to use R to do the integration. Here is my R code.

```
Int.func<-function(c)
{   
dnorm(c)^{9-0} * (dchisq(c, 2)^{5-0} + dchisq(c, 2)^{5-1} + dchisq(c, 2)^{5-2})+
dnorm(c)^{9-1} * (dchisq(c, 2)^{5-0} + dchisq(c, 2)^{5-1} )
}
integrate(Int.func, 0, Inf)
```

Is there a smart way to do the summation without adding one team at a time?

Comment: what do you mean by team?

Comment: For example: Can I make a loop for "dchisq(c, 2)^{5-0} + dchisq(c, 2)^{5-1} + dchisq(c, 2)^{5-2}" inside the function, like: sum i from 0 to 2 (dchisq(c, 2)^{5-i})?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `sum` function in R, you can use it to sum the results of a function on a vector. For example:

```
Int.func <- function(c){   
  x.fun  <- function(x, y) dchisq(y, 2)^{5-x}
  y.fun  <- function(y) dnorm(y)^{9-0} * sum(x.fun(0:2, y)) + dnorm(y)^{9-1} * sum(x.fun(0:1, y))
  sapply(c, y.fun)
}
integrate(Int.func, 0, Inf)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I also wanted to simplify the y.fun using sum, but it doesn't work. Do you know where I did wrong?

`Int.func <- function(c){   
  x.fun  <- function(x, y) dchisq(y, 2)^{5-x}
  m.fun  <- function(m, y) dnorm(y)^{9-m} * sum(x.fun(0:(2-m), y))
  y.fun  <- function(y) sum(m.fun(0:1, y))
  sapply(c, y.fun)
}
integrate(Int.func, 0, Inf)`

Comment: change `y.func` to `y.fun <- function(y) sum(sapply(0:1, m.fun, y=y))`